# mongoDB shell - getting out of db.find() resultset

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

When you query something in mongo using db.collection.find() and if the result set exceeds the max allowed shellBatchSize, mongo prints n number of records and says `type "it" for more`. If oyu don;t want to see more, How to get out of this and get back to mongo shell?

I know CTRL +C
I know converting the output to a JASON Array
I know diverting the output to a file.

I'm looking for some non-crude way (like CNTRL + C) to get back to mongo shell.

Thanks,

Comment: You're already back at the mongo shell prompt when it does that.

Comment: hmm.. interesting. But how can i run another query at the prompt without crudely getting out of mongo shell completely and coming back by: `>mongo > use db` etc..

Comment: Just type a new command at the `>` prompt. Maybe you're seeing something else?

Comment: let me try that...please ignore my reply.

Comment: OMG it is correct. Never realized that. I feel so ignorant. Sorry for a stupid question and many thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a query in the shell that results in `Type "it" for more`, you're already back at the main command prompt of the shell. You can just type a new command at the `>` prompt.